# Why does DISTINCT has to go first in MySQL?

Tags: mysql, sql, distinct

I have a query that works when I do

```
SELECT DISTINCT(table.field.id), 1 FROM ...
```

but fails when I do

```
SELECT 1, DISTINCT(table.field.id) FROM ...
```

Is this a known behavior?

Why does the first one work while the second doesn't?

Comment: `DISTINCT` is *not* a function.  `SELECT DISTINCT` is a clause in the SQL language.  `SELECT DISTINCT` applies to *all* columns in the clause.

Comment: `DISTINCT` means "eliminate duplicate rows". It doesn't make sense at the column level. This is why it stays [between `SELECT` and the list of selected expressions](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/select.html). To answer the question in title: because the [documentation of `SELECT`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/select.html) says so.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Unfortunately I'm not able to add a comment yet.

What @Gordon Linoff has written is exactly right. 
You are getting error as `DISTINCT` in general works as part of `SELECT` clause or `AGGREGATE` function. It is used to return unique rows from a result set and it can be used to force unique column values within an aggregate function.

Examples: `SELECT DISTINCT * ...` `COUNT(DISTINCT COLUMN)` or `SUM(DISTINCT COLUMN).`

More information's about `DISTINCT` in popular DB engines:

- PostgreSQL:https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.0/static/sql-select.html#SQL-DISTINCT
- SQL Server: https://www.techonthenet.com/sql_server/distinct.php
- Oracle: https://www.techonthenet.com/oracle/distinct.php
- MySQL:
  https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/distinct-optimization.html
  https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/select.html