# Using CASE in @Parameters

Tags: sql-server, parameters, reportbuilder, case-when

How can I use `case when .. then` in `@Parameters` in MS Report Builder?

For example this code does not work correct, because Filter does not work

```
SELECT DISTINCT case 
   when [APPROVAL_STATUS]  = 'approved' then '1'   
   when [APPROVAL_STATUS]  = 'denied' then '2'       
   when [APPROVAL_STATUS]  = 'pending'  then '3'       
   when isnull([APPROVAL_STATUS], ' ') = '' then '4'       
   ELSE [APPROVAL_STATUS] 
end as [APPROVAL_STATUS] 

FROM [dbo].[SUMMARY]
```

Is it possible?

Comment: @Sami You certainly can. Why not? You are not using `distinct` on a `case` though, [you are using it on a query](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/43193406/why-does-distinct-has-to-go-first-in-mysql#comment73459744_43193406). It does not matter that the query has a `case` in one of its columns.

Comment: @GSerg You are right that because `AS` keyword :)

Comment: @Sami Couldn't be. `select distinct <expression> as columnname` and `select distinct columnname = <expression>` are equally valid. [Works for me either way](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/41312b/2).

Comment: @GSerg Yup , I'll check and update , seems like his code work fine

Comment: What you mean by "Filter does not work"?